# Trying to find a better way to implement a recursive depth first search

Tags: list-manipulation, graphs-and-networks, recursion

I'm trying to implementa recursive depth first search. It works and the result is below:

```
e = 
  {1 \[UndirectedEdge] 2, 1 \[UndirectedEdge] 3, 
   2 \[UndirectedEdge] 4, 2 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   3 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 4 \[UndirectedEdge] 5, 
   4 \[UndirectedEdge] 6, 5 \[UndirectedEdge] 6};
nG = Graph[e, VertexLabels -> Automatic];

Clear[DFS, getVisited];
getVisited[am_?MatrixQ] := 
  Module[{length = Length[am[[1]]]},
    visited = ConstantArray[False, length];
    visited];
DFS[am_?MatrixQ, n_?IntegerQ] := 
  Module[{i, l = Length[visited]},
    visited[[n]] = True;
    Print["Visited: " , n];
    For[i = 1, i <= l, ++i,
    If[am[[n, i]] == 1 && visited[[i]] == False, DFS[am, i]]]];

visited = getVisited[AdjacencyMatrix[nG]];
DFS[AdjacencyMatrix[nG], 4]
```

> `4, 2, 1, 3, 5, 6`

The problem is in the implementation. As the list of visited vertices should be global, I need to call the function `getVisited` before calling my main function to firstly get the global array. This operation seems like a redundant one and I'm looking for another more neat approach. If you have some ideas it would be great.

Comment: What about just using `visited = ConstantArray[False, VertexCount[nG]]` instead?

Comment: Btw. you might want to let the `For` loop run only over the `i`s in `am["AdjacencyLists"][[n]]`. And better use a `Do` loop instead.

Comment: Also the recursive approach has many shortcomings. One hits the `$RecursionLimit` quite quickly for larger graphs.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Depth-first search is already implemented in the built-in function [`DepthFirstScan`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DepthFirstScan.html), but I assume you don't just want to use it but learn how to implement this algorithm in Mathematica. I would do it as follows:

It is convenient to use an adjacency list representation of the graph. I will use `IGAdjacencyList` from [IGraph/M](http://szhorvat.net/mathematica/IGraphM), which works reliably for all sort of graphs. For simple undirected graphs, you may use `AssociationThread[VertexList[g], AdjacencyList[g]]` as an alternative that does not require IGraph/M.

The implementation:

```
dfs[g_?GraphQ, v0_, f_] := 
 Module[{visited, rec, al = IGAdjacencyList[g]},
  If[Not@VertexQ[g, v0], Return[$Failed]]; (* check that the input is valid *)
  visited[_] := False;
  rec[v_?visited] := Null;
  rec[v_] := (visited[v] = True; f[v]; rec /@ al[v]);
  rec[v0];
 ]
```

`g` is the input graph, `v0` is the starting vertex, and `f` is a function that will be evaluated for each vertex as they are visited. You may use [`Sow`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Sow.html) to collect them in to a list, or [`Print`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) to just display them.

Demonstration with your graph:

```
dfs[nG, 4, Print]

4

2

1

3

5

6
```

Explanation of the function:

- `visited` is a local symbol which is used to keep track of which vertices have been visited.
- `rec` is the function that traverses the graph recursively. It takes a vertex as input. For each neighbour of this vertex, 1) it checks if it has already been visited 2) if not, it calls `f`, marks it as visited, and applies itself to all its neighbours.

Alternatively, you could make `visited` an association and return its keys at the end.

```
dfs2[g_?GraphQ, v0_, f_] := 
 Module[{visited = <||>, rec, al = IGAdjacencyList[g]}, 
  If[Not@VertexQ[g, v0], Return[$Failed]];
  rec[v_?visited] := Null;
  rec[v_] := (AssociateTo[visited, v -> True]; f[v]; rec /@ al[v]);
  rec[v0];
  Keys[visited]
 ]
```